# rename a file if another file exists in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been looking for the way to do this using `get-children` and `rename` combined with `if` but no luck.

I want to search all subdirectories (subdir1, subdir2, etc) of a directory (test) for a file `"trigger.txt"` and if the file exists in one of these subdirectories I want to change the name of another file in the same subdirectory (`changeme.txt` to `_changeme.txt`)

Rephrasing:

If file `subdir1\"trigger.txt"` exists change `subdir1\"changename.txt"` to `subdir1\"_changename.txt"`

I have found scripts to change the name of file if it exists and to look for a file but I cannot connect it together... Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -r trigger.txt | Foreach {Rename-Item (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName changeme.txt)  _changeme.txt}
```

And if you want the terse version:

```
ls -r trigger.txt | %{rni (join-path $_.DirectoryName changeme.txt) _changeme.txt}
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. I used the second one. This really saved me a lot of effort. I only added `cd 'd:\test'` in the first line of script to execute it in the chosen directory.

Comment: Or you could specify that path to Get-ChildItem e.g. `Get-ChildItem d:\test -r trigger.txt | ...`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
ls -filter trigger.txt -recurse | %{
    $original = Join-Path $(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent) "ChangeMe.txt"
    $newName  = Join-Path $(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent) "_ChangeMe.txt"

    if ([IO.File]::Exists($original)) {
        Write-Host "Renaming $($original)..."
        ren -Path $original -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

Comment: This script also works perfectly with screen output as a bonus but I am after hiding the ruuunig PS script when it runs so I wrap it into VBS script either way. Thank you!